# jquery POST params

Tags: jquery, rest, post

I have a function that is making a POST call and I keep getting this for a response from the server:

```
{
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Missing required parameter client_id"
}
```

This is the function I'm using to make the POST call:

```
  function isUserRegistered() {
      user_code = localStorage.getItem('LSuserCode');
      // POST for user object   
      $.post("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token", {
              client_id: clientID,
              client_secret: clientSecret,
              grant_type: 'authorization_code',
              redirect_uri: redirectURI,
              code: user_code
          },
          function(data) {
              grabUserAccessTok(data);
          });
  }
```

It's complaining that I am missing a required "client_id" parameter but as you can see from my POST call, it is in there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: check the network tab in your browser dev tools to inspect the request and see what values are sent

Comment: is your `client_id` null? do you have value in `clientID` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your JQuery code, it seems that you use the method `post` correctly. So I think that you should do the following things:

- Get the exact input structure for this endpoint (documentation, ...)
- Have a look at the actual content sent by the request using Chrome DevTools, Firebug or something else

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Use  [ ] with params

```
$.post("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token", {[
              client_id: clientID,
              client_secret: clientSecret,
              grant_type: 'authorization_code',
              redirect_uri: redirectURI,
              code: user_code
          ]},
          function(data) {
              grabUserAccessTok(data);
          });
```